# overriden isEqual method not getting called every time during comparisons

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a class called

```
Contact;
```

In `Contact` I have `(simple version to test, no hash yet)`

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)other {
    if (other == self)
        return YES;
    if (!other || ![other isKindOfClass:[self class]])
        return NO;
    return NO;
}
```

I do:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
Contact *contact = [Contact new];
[arr addObject:contact]

// I expect my isEqual to be called here but it does not get called
[arr containsObject:contact] // this evaluates to true somehow!!!
```

However if I add a another object to type `NSString`, then it gets called for comparing String object but not for the contact object. Which means

```
[arr addObject:@""] // so now arr has two elements

// here I expect two calls to isEqual but only one gets there
// when comparing string object against Contact
[arr containsObject:contact]
```

Why is `isEqual` not getting called in cases I mentioned above??

Comment: Probably just a nit, but you do mean `NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` (two open brackets) not `NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];` right? and `[arr addObject:@""]` (using `@` for NSString literal). And does Contact specify that it implements NSObject protocol?

Comment: yes...I just made the edit!

Comment: silly question but how are you verifying your isEqual: override does not get called? Breakpoint or NSLog...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please read the discussion about `isEqual:` in the NSObject Protocol in the [Reference Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/).

You'll find that for objects which are inside a collection (such as an NSArray), `hash` might be used to determine whether two objects are actually the same. If two pointers are actually pointing to the same object, there is no need to check for equality - hence `isEqual:` never gets called.

The solution as suggested by the reference library is to implement `hash` in your subclass as well.

Comment: I doubt the `-hash` method is involved in this case. An `NSArray` is not a hash-based collection. Also, the `-isEqual:` method in the question maintains the semantics of `-[NSObject isEqual:]`, so the inherited `-hash` is fine. Finally, if two objects are equal their hashes must be the same, but if their hashes are the same that doesn't imply they are equal (hashes collide by their nature). So, even if `NSArray` used the hash and found two were the same, it would still have to call `-isEqual:` to verify. The probable reason is just that `NSArray` checks for pointer equality before `-isEqual:`.

Comment: It's not your bug. Put multiple `Contact` objects in the array. Create yet another one (not in the array) and ask the array if it contains the object. It will call `-isEqual:` against all of the ones in the array, because none is at the same address. (It will return false because the array doesn't contain an equal object.) Now change your `-isEqual:` and `-hash` so two different `Contact`s can in fact be equal. Search for an equal but not identical object and you'll see calls to `-isEqual:` until it finds a match.

Comment: @KenThomases I did what you suggested....isEqual is as per expectations.......in you suggestion do you expect hash to get called....I have 4 new objects in array....each object has a different id (1,2,3,4)...I created 5 first with id = 5....isEqual returned false for all 4 elements .......and then id = 1.....isEqual returned true for 1 element.....but hash was not called in any case....I hope it was NOT expected to be called...

Comment: I did not expect `-hash` to be called. You can experiment with an `NSSet` to see hash get called. I said you had to change your implementation of `-hash` because you pretty much always have to when you change your implementation of `-isEqual:`, for general correctness (not specifically for this case).